# Adding protection against hotlinking to .htaccess breaks generation of styled images

Tags: 8, media, .htaccess

Drupal 8.3.4, Apache, Image Magick toolkit (via Imagick module).

I recently discovered some annoying hotlinking to my site siphoning my bandwidth and decided to disable it. Added the following to /sites/default/files/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://[my-domain] [NC]
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

The hotlinking stopped (my images don't display on rogue pages anymore), my site in general seems to be working well BUT styled images stopped being generated. Any attempt to access a styled image not yet generated results in error 403.
Evidently the lines in the .htaccess somehow interfere with the toolkit (or its Drupal wrapper) operation but I can't figure out in what way. One thing that is clear is that as soon as I revert the .htaccess back to default things start working (including hotlinking) and as soon as I reintroduce those lines both hotlinking and styled image generation stop working.
Will appreciate any insight.

Comment: Hmm, looks right to me.  Are you using https?  You might need to change http to http(s)?.  Also, the Rewrite rule should be \.(gif...  to select just a dot and not any character.

Comment: I am not using https but I have tried that too among many things, and the dot is properly escaped now - still doesn't generate styles...

Comment: Are you using some sort of front end for the site?  E.g. varnish, cloudflare, nginx?  It might be that your referrer tag is not what you think it is.  So all images are being blocked... except image styles since they have a ?token=... parameter and this will not match your block rule.

Comment: Nope, no front end - plain vanilla Drupal on the front. And in all log messages the referer is what I think it is. And all existing images are displayed correctly on the site - styled or not, it's just that styled versions of newly added images are not created (while full-size newly added images are displayed ok).

Comment: Playing around with various workarounds for "image styles not generated" found on the net, tried to "allow_insecure_derivatives" and "suppress_itok_output" in the settings.php image.settings. And it worked, so you were right that tokens had something to do with it! But I still don't understand why exactly it didn't work with tokens and I am reluctant to accept that as a permanent solution as I am opening the site to possible DDoS attacks...